# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10

Tags: java, android, logcat, android-library

I am trying to create a particle text view animation Using [Yasic](https://github.com/Yasic/ParticleTextView) library but when I run my code on a physical device I get inflate exception error. 
I haven't figured out the problem yet and it would be a great help if you show me some solutions to this error.

here is my java code

> Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ParticleTextView particleTextView1 = (ParticleTextView) findViewById(R.id.particleTextView1);
        ParticleTextViewConfig config1 = new ParticleTextViewConfig.Builder()
                .setTargetText("Loading")
                .setReleasing(0.4)
                .setParticleRadius(4)
                .setMiniDistance(1)
                .setTextSize(150)
                .setRowStep(9)
                .setColumnStep(9)
                .instance();


            particleTextView1.setConfig(config1);
            particleTextView1.startAnimation();

  }
}
```

Logcat error here

> Logcat

```
09-18 22:31:52.809 7418-7418/com.codecrafted.udit.particle E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.codecrafted.udit.particle, PID: 7418
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.codecrafted.udit.particle/com.codecrafted.udit.particle.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.yasic.library.particletextview.View.ParticleTexView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2747)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6365)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:883)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.yasic.library.particletextview.View.ParticleTexView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.yasic.library.particletextview.View.ParticleTexView
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.yasic.library.particletextview.View.ParticleTexView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.codecrafted.udit.particle-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.codecrafted.udit.particle-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:812)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:752)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:883)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:522)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:430)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.codecrafted.udit.particle.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6852)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2700)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6365)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:883)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
```

Comment: My first guess would be that Proguard is removing the Yasic classes at build time. Search around for how to configure Proguard to `keep` your Yasic classes and maybe that will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `ParticleTextView` in `onCreate()` method first.

```
private ParticleTextView particleTextView1
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        particleTextView1 = (ParticleTextView) findViewById(R.id.particleTextView1);
}
```

Then in your xml, make sure it starts by:

```
<com.yasic.library.particletextview.View.ParticleTextView
```

I'm guessing that initializing the view inside `onResume()` method might cause this issue since it might not be created at first runtime in `onCreate()` method.